# CGImage to NSImage with Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to create an NSImage from a CGImage, but keep on getting these errors. I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithCGImage:size:)
and I've tried to use the hints in xcode.

[image: Extra argument 'size' in call]

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import CoreGraphics

let image = NSImage(named:"image")
if let image = image {
    var imageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    var imageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)

    var leftImageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/2.0, image.size.height)
    var leftImageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    var leftImage = NSImage(CGImage:leftImageRef, size:NSZeroSize)

    var rightImageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(image.size.width/2.0, 0, image.size.width/2.0, image.size.height)
    var rightImageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    var rightImage = NSImage(CGImage:rightImageRef)
    var testImage = NSImage(CGImage:rightImageRef, flipped:)

}
```

Comment: Next time, please paste your code. An image of code is of no use to anyone. Remember, your question should make it possible for others to reproduce your issue. If you can't take the time to do that, don't ask a question at all.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time using Xcode and Swift so I thought it was just a simple thing I was overlooking. I wanted to show the exact error in Xcode so that it'd be more clear.

Comment: There's a way to copy the error and paste it. If you don't know that way, sure, you can show an image of the error. But to reproduce the problem and thus assist you requires code that others can copy and paste. You forced me to type your code by hand, squinting at your picture. I didn't enjoy that at all. :( Let's be considerate...

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the help and feedback, I'll definitely do that in the future. Post edited also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `leftImageRef` is *not* a CGImage. It is an `Unmanaged<CGImage>?`. You need to unwrap it and provide memory management before you can work with it.

If you say `leftImageRef!.takeUnretainedValue()` you will get a CGImage. (The forced unwrapping should be safe, but if you are worried that this NSImage might not be able to draw, you can of course unwrap more carefully.)

Comment: You could easily have solved this yourself just by putting the cursor in `leftImageRef` at the declaration point, and looking at Quick Help. That is what I did, and that is how I learned that this is an `Unmanaged<CGImage>?`. The rest is a trivial consequence. Always examine what type you've got; it might not be what you think!

Comment: Thanks! First time using Xcode, I should probably read more about its features! :)